# Error TS2304 when calling generic function inside generic arrow function

Tags: typescript, generics, arrow-functions

Why does Typescript raises an error when I try to call a generic function, from an arrow function using the supplied type parameter.

```js
function a<T>() { }
function b<T>() { a<T>() } // no errors
const c: <T>() => void = () => a<T>() // cannot find name T. ts(2304)
```

**EDIT**

This question arose while I was trying to write a generic arrow function 
 similar to `c` in a `.tsx` file.

In this case, all of the following syntaxes raises an error.

```js
const c: <T>() => void = <T>() => a<T>()
    //^ Type 'Element' is not assignable to type '<T>() => void'.
       // Type 'Element' provides no match for the signature '<T>(): void'.ts(2322)
```

```js
const c = <T>() => a<T>() 
         //^ JSX element 'T' has no corresponding closing tag.ts(17008)
```

In the end, I chose to use the regular function syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you declare T in the type definition of `c`.
That is how it should look

```
const c: <T>() => void = <T>() => a<T>()
```